# Upload a photo PHP

Tags: php, upload, photo

strangest thing happened... I created a webshop in PHP. Everything worked fine, but when we moved the website from our ftp to theirs, we ran into a problem. We aren't able to upload pictures anymore...

```
        if (file_exists("../productimages/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"]))
    {
        $feedback = "<div class=\"voegproducttoefeedback\">Please change name of product<b><big> \"".$_FILES["picture"]["name"] . "\"
        </big></b>The name already occurs in the database</div> ";
    } else
        {

        $tmp_name = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
        $name = $_FILES["picture"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "../productimages/$name");


        if(file_exists("../productimages/$name")) {
         $feedback2 = "succeed";
        }
        else {
                $feedback2 = "failed";
        }

     if ($product->saveproduct($_DB)) {
        $feedback = "<div class=\"voegproducttoefeedback\">Product <b><big>\"".$product->naam."\"</big></b> created with succes</div>";
      } else {
        $feedback = "<div class=\"voegproducttoefeedback\">Not enough information to create product</div>";
      }
    }}}?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the target directory permissions (../productimages/)

Comment: Maybe Michiel is not even has access to `../` on the other server.

Comment: Also, make sure that the directory exists at that relative location.

Comment: Right on productimages and the root (httpdocs) are 775. More than enough I hope :)
@Phoenix, what doe you mean?

Comment: Make sure the directory structure is the same.  If `../productimages` is not there relative to the working directory of the script, then it can't produce an image there.  So, if there is a directory `/html` (web root), `/html/script`, and a directory `/html/productimages`, then if the script is run in `/html/script` it will work, because it goes back to `/html` and then up to `/productimages`, however, if the script is included through a script in `/html` then that is it's working directory, and it will go down to the dir below `/html` and then try finding `/productimages` there.

Comment: To get around this, don't use relative paths, use an absolute path, like `/home/user/public_html/productimages`, which can either be done manually in the file, or via a constant or variable set somewhere in a config file included like `$basepath = /home/user/public_html` and then  `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$basepath/productimages/$name");` or `file_exists($basepath . "/productimages/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"])`, or it can be done with the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` superglobal var.

Comment: the structure is: /httpdocs (root) - /httpdocs/productimages * /httpdocs/content/product.php => script is generated in the product.php file

Comment: Well, that would function quite well. It's probably the directory permissions then.  777 might be required to get it to work if 775 doesn't. Keep the root at stricter permissions though. Just remember to use `chmod();` on the files after moving them so they aren't writable by everyone, and also use .htaccess to turn off running scripts and indices in the image directory.  You can turn off scripts by adding `AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .jsp .asp .sh .cgi`(new line)`Options -ExecCGI` to the .htaccess in the productimages directory.   The extensions after AddHandler will not be allowed to run.

Comment: You can also set it to also only allow viewing of certain file types for extra security like: `<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$">` (new line)
 `Order Allow,Deny`(new line)
 `Allow from all`(new line)
`</FilesMatch>`, though you might also have to do one which will also deny all other files.

Answer (score 0):

As Goo says, check permissions, but also ensure that PHP is configured to allow uploads and that the maximum upload size is set correctly.

Check file_uploads is set to 'on' and upload_max_filesize is set to a sensible limit.

Comment: But the same script does work on my private server... Just not on theirs... Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, this is common - although the scripts are the same, the underlying environments (both PHP and the host OS) may differ.  For file upload you rely on a number of configurations to be set correctly for this to work.  Even the web server could be configured differently leading to problems, but this is less likely in your instance.

Comment: Where can I add this file_upload and upload_max_filesize? .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to them, check your PHP error logs.

Your host most likely hasn't enabled write permissions for the account in charge of the PHP process. You'll need to see if they can enable that.

Comment: How do I access them? I've access to the root of the server, but I guess I just received some kind of an account to upload onto the ftp. Not the root access itself

Comment: Depends on your host's setup. You'd have to get in touch with them to figure out what access (if any) they provide to those logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem (partial) solved. I changed the permissions of productimages... But the success of the process required a 777 permission... Not very secure though. Here is my structure, maybe you can see the problem...

The above script is in products.php

http://img695.imageshack.us/i/schermafbeelding2011010kt.png/

Answer (score 0):

In [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610245/upload-a-photo-php/4611028#4611028), you said:

> Ok, problem (partial) solved. I changed the permissions of productimages...
>   But the success of the process required a 777 permission... Not very secure though

The best way to resolve this is to change the ownership of the directory to the user the webserver runs as. However, this will require root access to the server (or the `sudo` command), which you most likely don't have. So here's a workaround:

1. Rewrite your script to check if `productimages` exists and, if not, create it:

   `if(!is_dir('../productimages/')) mkdir('../productimages/', 0755);`
2. Then, delete the `productimages` directory. You're going to let the script re-create it for you. When it does, the webserver's user will own the script.
3. In order to make this happen, `chmod 777` *the parent directory. **This is only temporary**, and allows the script to create the directory.
4. Run the script. Make sure it created the `productimages` directory. If it did, `chmod 755` back the parent directoy.

This should enable you to get the permissions you need as well as have control over the access of the directory.

Comment: Sounds promising... But for some reason, the script won't run... Can you write a bit more script please?

Comment: Sorry, `mkdir('../productimages/'), 0755)` should have been `mkdir('../productimages/', 0755);`